# Copy a single commit from another branch, with no new commits

Tags: git

The most similar way to do it is:

`git cherry-pick COMMIT_HASH`

But this creates a new commit. So when I merge I get two identical commits with different hashes.

Comment: It's not clear why you think this is a problem.  The point of doing a merge later is to pick up one copy of all the changes made since the common *merge base* of your current commit and the commit you're merging-in.  If you have cherry-picked another commit, that generally means you have two copies of the changes, but Git usually deals with that just fine in its merge process of finding "one copy of changes since base".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible.

The ID of a commit is a unique cryptographic checksum of the contents of the commit—which should immediately make you ask: "What *are* the contents of a commit?"

To answer that, take a look at a sample commit:

```
$ git cat-file -p HEAD
```

for instance.  You'll see something along these lines:

```
tree 80e2d6ce407585c136ab90a6aba1fcb807e7e042
parent 31305025f20182017855793ebce8b122b1396246
author A U Thor <thor@example.com> 1475588570 -0700
committer A U Thor <thor@example.com> 1475588740 -0700

commit message
```

That, literally (though in this case with a few edits), is the complete contents of a commit: a `tree` line, some `parent` lines (usually just one), an `author` line, a `committer` line, a blank line, and your commit message.

Suppose you copy some other commit, even down to using the same `tree` (the `tree` is the ID of a unique Git object representing the snapshot Git makes of your work-tree<sup>1</sup>).  Suppose you somehow trick Git into putting the same time-stamp in, even though it's probably days, or hours, or even just a few seconds later now, than it was when you made that other commit.  Suppose you also copy the commit message exactly.  If you're on a *different* branch with a different *current* commit, though, the `parent` line of the new copy will be different.

The `parent` line tells Git which commit comes immediately before any given commit.  So each *new* commit makes the branch name point to the new commit, while the new commit points back to the previous commit.  The unique ID of a commit depends not only on the source snapshot, author and committer name/email/timestamp, and commit message.  It *also* depends on the *previous* commit ID—which in turn depends on its own previous commit ID, and so on all the way back in history.

In other words, the unique commit ID not only identifies just one specific commit, it *also* specifies the *entire history*: the IDs of *every* commit leading up to that particular commit.

---

<sup>1</sup>More precisely, the `tree` is made from the contents of the index / staging-area.  This is why you need to `git add` changes into the staging area: if you don't, the modified files will not be in the next commit.

Answer (score 3):

Try using **no-commit** for that:

```
git cherry-pick --no-commit COMMIT_HASH
```

This should get the changes from that commit, but stops right before committing them from the staging area.

Comment: So, what next? Use `git add .` and `git commit`? But this creates a new commit! I want EXACTLY this commit... Like when I merge it to my branch. But I can't merge it coz I want a single commit, not all the list. 
I am starting to think it's not possible.

Comment: @JerryGreen that's not possible.  A commit contains information about its parent. Because you have different branches, the parents are different too and commits will always be different.

Comment: @Jerry Depending on your use case, you could rewrite history by amending or squashing the changes from the cherry pick, so you'd only have one commit.